# Installing Spark in Laravel - The command doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

I am trying to install Spark in Laravel using [its own documentation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/3.0/installation). Everything has been installed fine, however when I get to the:

```
php artisan spark:install --force
```

part my command prompt simply won't work.

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  There are no commands defined in the "spark" namespace.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `composer require laravel/spark` looks like you don't have it.

Then don't forget to add the service providers in you `config/app.php` file and you should be good to run your command.